# How to derive relations between the sides and angles of equilateral hyperbolic triangles

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling

I hope everyone in this community is staying safe, well and isolated. In this unprecedented situation I am starting to learn about some non-Euclidean geometry and explore down a fractal.

> In the comments and answers to my question, I hope to find a visual way and get hints toward understanding the derivation of the following hyperbolic trigonometric formulas:
>   $$
> \cos \alpha    = \frac{\tanh \frac12 s}{\tanh s} \qquad\qquad
> \cosh\frac12 s = \frac{\cos  \frac12 \alpha}{\sin\alpha}
> $$
>   where $s$ is the side, and $\alpha$ the angle, of an equilateral hyperbolic triangle.

Is there a visual way to construct an understanding for the latter formula? I included a visual from the Wikipedia on the [Poincaré disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) (or conformal disk model) which shows the hyperbolic model in green over the unit disk and curves being projected onto the disk. Can this visual (or any other visual) be used to come up with the trigonometry of the hyperbolic plane?

[image: y]

Sorry if this question is not specific but my end goal for this exploration is to construct a [tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octagonal_tiling) of the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: This isn't what you're after, but just to mention it ... The [Hyperbolic Laws of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines) give rise to the somewhat-simpler relations $$\cos\alpha = \frac{\cosh s}{1+\cosh s} \qquad \cosh s = \frac{\cos\alpha}{1-\cos\alpha}$$ that, with the help of half- and double-angle identities, can be massaged into the forms given in the question. ... Would demonstrations of these versions of the relations be acceptable?

Comment: One also observes that the first relation in the question is a direct application of the hyperbolic right-triangle trigonometric formula 
$$\cos\theta = \frac{\tanh(\text{adjacent})}{\tanh(\text{hypotenuse})}$$ Dropping an altitude from a vertex of our equilateral triangle creates a right triangle with acute angle $\alpha$, hypotenuse length $s$, and "adjacent" length $s/2$. This raises the question: What "base-line" trigonometric facts are in play here? Could you start with the cosine formula in this comment, or would you need *that* proven, too?

Comment: I need that proven too. I am having trouble "seeing" the fact that $\cos\theta = \frac{\tanh(\text{adjacent})}{\tanh(\text{hypotenuse})}$. This looks a lot like $\cos(\theta)=\frac{\text{adj}}{\text{hyp}}$ and I am finding a similar formula for $\sin\theta = \frac{\sinh(\text{opp})}{\sinh(\text{hyp})}$ but how do you construct these triangles? For example if you three non-coplanar points a b and c, would you just fit a hyperbola between these points? Thanks for your comment sorry for the confusion.